# Add an external Project dependency to my Play application

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, dependency-management, typesafe-activator

At the moment I am using a pretty basic build.sbt file which was created by activator and gives me a Play application

My goal is to add an external Project dependency to my Play application.

My build.sbt file looks along the lines of

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
...
)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
pipelineStages := Seq(rjs, digest, gzip)
```

Is the only way to add a dependency on an external project to change to using a build.scala file?
If so, is it possible for the Build.scala file to reference the current build.sbt file?

The external project also has its own Build.scala file, so is it possible to reference from the "master" Build file to the external projects?

Thanks

Comment: The build.sbt is missing blanklines (yea, ugh), but Where is the other file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Publish to Ivy and resolve (see:   http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Publishing.html#Publishing+Locally)
2. Directly reference the other project, e.g in your build.sbt.

Here's what option #2 looks like:

```
lazy val other = file("/path/to/other").getAbsoluteFile.toURI

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala).dependsOn(other)
```

Comment: Great thanks, this works - as a extra note, as the project I was depending on had 2 project structure itself, I ended up having to use a slightly different sub-project definition lazy val oauthProvider = ProjectRef(file("/Working/scala-services/AS/scala-oauth2-provider").getAbsoluteFile.toURI, "play2-oauth2-provider")

Comment: Yep, I should have mentioned the ProjectRef bit.

Comment: Hi, option #2 seems to only work if your library project is a sub-project of the play's project tree. Can you please elaborate how to include external java project which is outside the play project directory? Also, can you explain which of the options is more simple and preferred ?